# Javascript chaining promise seemingly change execution order

Tags: javascript, promise

In the following code

```
let urls = [
  'https://api.github.com/users/iliakan',
];

//let requests = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url).then(() => { console.log('Prout')}));
let requests = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url));
console.log('Start');

axios.get(urls[0])
  .then((responses) => {
    console.log('Got Response');
    return Promise.all(requests);
  }).then((resp) => {
    console.log('Finished Mapping');
  });
```

The console print out the expected

> Start
>
> Got response
>
> Finished Mapping

But if you switch with the commented out definition then I get on the console

> Start
>
> Prout
>
> Got response
>
> Finished Mapping

...as if the interpreted reordered the logging of 'Got Response' and the execution of promises in requests.

What is happening here ?

Comment: What's the point of fetching `urls[0]` twice?

Comment: @Bergi: this is just a dummy example, there is no point to that code except the trick thing that happen with order of logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in both case the same order applies, the only difference is that `let requests = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url));` does not print anything.

This is because of the ajax calls are executed when mapping them, and the nested `.then` will be executed whenever the node thread is free.

If you really want to have this order

```
Start

Got response

Prout

Finished Mapping
```

You need to chain the promises properly, i.e.

```
const axios = require('axios');

let urls = [
  'https://api.github.com/users/iliakan',
];

let requests = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url));
console.log('Start');

axios.get(urls[0])
  .then((responses) => {
    console.log('Got Response');

    return Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
      axios.get(url).then(() => { console.log('Prout'); })
    ));
  }).then((resp) => {
    console.log('Finished Mapping');
  });
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The request is sent when `axios.get(url)` is called during the `urls.map(…)` call. It does not wait for the promise to be passed into `Promise.all`.

If you want to chain the execution to have them run sequentially, you need to put those calls inside the `then` callback as well:

```
let urls = [
  'https://api.github.com/users/iliakan',
];

console.log('Start');    
axios.get(urls[0])
  .then(responses => {
    console.log('Got Response');
    const requests = urls.map(url =>
      axios.get(url).then(() => { console.log('Prout'); })
    );
    return Promise.all(requests);
  }).then(resp => {
    console.log('Finished Mapping');
  });
```